# Powershell comparing data in a CSV against files in a folder

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm fairly new to powershell.

I'm trying to compare data in a CSV File against random files in a specific folder.

I want to see if and what has changed and then log that in another column called "Changed".

Here's what I've done below, it seems to create a new column called 'Changed' but doesn't input the changes in it.

```
$Spreadsheet     = 'C:\Powershell\CSV\inv.csv'   
$SpreadSheetPath = "C:\Powershell\CSV"

Import-Csv $Spreadsheet -Delimiter "|" -Encoding Default | ForEach-Object -
{
    $Path += $_.Path    
    $Filename += $_.Filename    
    $DateModified += $_.DateModified    
    $FileSize += $_.FileSize  
    $MD5Hash += $_.MD5Hash
}

{  
    $Msg1 = "Path changed"    
    $Msg2 = "File Name changed"  
    $Msg3 = "Date Modified changed"  
    $Msg4 = "File Size changed"   
    $Msg5 = "MD5 changed"  
    $Msg6 = "Files are the same"  
    $psdata = "D:\ps-test\data\*.*"  
}        

If (($Path -eq $psdata))
{
    Import-Csv C:\Powershell\CSV\inv.csv |
        Select-Object *,@{Name='Changed';Expression={$Msg6}} |
        Export-Csv C:\Powershell\CSV\NewSpreadsheet4.csv
}   
Else   
{
    Import-Csv C:\Powershell\CSV\inv.csv |
        Select-Object *,@{Name='Changed';Expression={$Msg1}} |
        Export-Csv C:\Powershell\CSV\NewSpreadsheet4.csv
}
```

Here is an example of what the CSV looks like:

```
Path     Filename   Date Modified   File Size   MD5 Hash
D:\ps-test\data adminmodeinfo.htm   03/11/2010 22:42    1079    BD1C9468D71FD33BB35716630C4EC6AC
E:\ps-test\data admintoolinfo.htm   03/11/2010 22:42    868 24B99B6316F0C49C23F27FEA6FF1C6AC
E:\ps-test\data admin_ban.bmp   03/11/2010 22:42    63480   C856F1F3C58962B456E749F2EA9C933A
E:\ps-test\data baseline.dat    03/20/2010 03:18:33 173818  F13183D88AABD1A725437802F8551A06
E:\ps-test\data blueRule.gif    03/11/2010 22:42    815 D1AEFE884935095DAB42DAFD072AA46F
E:\ps-test\data deffactory.dat  03/20/2010 03:18:33 706 862D4DFD2F49021BB7C145BDAFE62F6F
E:\ps-test\data dividerArt.jpg  03/11/2010 22:42    367 F7050C596C097C0B01A443058CD15E35
```

Comment: You should probably provide an excerpt from your CSV file so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @marsze, i've provided an example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code.I will try to highlight a few of the issues, link to documentation and point you in the right direction so that you can resolve your issues. A proper solution would require getting many more requirements, or writing code (off-topic for StackOverflow)

- Change
  `| ForEach-Object -
  {`
  to
  `| ForEach-Object {`
- In the [`Foreach-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), you are concatenating values from each line because you are using `+=`.
  On the first run, `$Path` contains `D:\ps-test\data`.
  After the second run, it contains `D:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\data`.
  At the end of your test data, it contains `D:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\dataE:\ps-test\data`
- The messages are contained in a [script block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks), but it does not look like this is intentional as this is never executed. So after the scriptblock, the variable `$Msg1` has not been created; it's blank.
- `If (($Path -eq $psdata))`

  - double brackets not required.
  - will always be false because the variable `$psdata` does not exist as it was stated inside a script block.
  - will always be false because you are attempting to equate the strings; your input does not literally contain `"D:\ps-test\data\*.*"`. You probably want `-like` instead of `-eq`.
  - will always be inaccurate because even if the paths are compared, there is no check that the file actually exists on the system.

---

**Useful links**

- [`Test-Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) to check if file exists.
- [`Get-FileHash`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) to get MD5 hash and compare to file.
- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to get a list of directories/files in a directory.
- [`Write-Output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) so that you can print variables and make sure they contain what you expect.
- [about_comparison_operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) - `-in` and `-contains` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion to help you get started. **It's not complete and not tested!** Let me know if it works as expected and if you have any questions.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Powershell\CSV\inv.csv' -Delimiter "|" -Encoding Default | foreach {
    $Path += $_.Path
    $Filename += $_.Filename
    $DateModified += $_.DateModified
    $FileSize += $_.FileSize
    $MD5Hash += $_.MD5Hash
    $file = [System.IO.FileInfo](Join-Path $Path $Filename)
    if (-not $file.Exists) {
        $message = "File does not exist"
    }
    elseif ($file.LastWriteTime -ne [DateTime]$DateModified) {
        $message = "Dates differ"
    }
    elseif ($file.Length -ne [int]$FileSize) {
        $message = "Sizes differ"
    }
    # and so on...
    # (You cannot really compared a changed file name btw)

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop @{
        Path = $Path
        Filename = $Filename
        DateModified = $DateModified
        FileSize = $FileSize
        MD5Hash = $MD5Hash
        Message = $message
    }
} | Export-CSV 'C:\Powershell\CSV\NewSpreadsheet4.csv'
```

Comment: I got this error?

Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Powershell\Help.ps1:7 char:44
+     $file = [System.IO.FileInfo](Join-Path $Path $Filename)
+                                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Pow 
   erShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
 
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Comment: Check the import csv. Check if all properties are assigned correctly. If the example is correct, you might have to change the delimiter.

Comment: I've checked the import CSV and all properties but still still getting the same error aswell as this:


'Cannot convert value 
"D:\ps-test\data\4212242656_3d87d21fc3_o.jpgD:\ps-test\data\4212242656_3d87d21fc3_o.jpg\" 
to type "System.IO.FileInfo". Error: "The given path's format is not supported."
At line:56 char:5
+     $file = [System.IO.FileInfo](Join-Path $Path $Filename)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastConstructorException'

Comment: I think the problem is very obvious here. (Both paths are rooted, unlike the csv data you posted.) I cannot do all of the work for you.